# Scrapy, Parse items from 1st page then a follow link to get additional items

Tags: python, callback, scrapy

Update: I was able to get this moving, but it doesn't return to the subpage and iterate the sequence again.
The data I am trying to extract is in a table like this:

Table
date_1   |  source_1   | link to article_1 |
date_2   |  source_2   | link to article_2 |
etc....

and I need to first collect the date_1, source_1 and then go into the link for the article and repeat...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from dirbot.items import WebsiteLoader
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse



class DindexSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "dindex"
allowed_domains = ["newslookup.com"]
start_urls = [
      "http://www.newslookup.com/Business/"
]

def parse_subpage(self, response):
    self.log("Scraping: " + response.url)
    il = response.meta['il']
    time = response.xpath('//div[@id="update_data"]//td[@class="stime3"]//text()').extract()
    il.add_value('publish_date', time)
    yield il.load_item()


def parse(self, response):
    self.log("Scraping: " + response.url)
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//td[@class="article"]')

    for site in sites:
        il = WebsiteLoader(response=response, selector=site)
        il.add_xpath('name', 'a/text()')
        il.add_xpath('url', 'a/@href')
        yield Request("http://www.newslookup.com/Business/", meta={'il': il}, callback=self.parse_subpage)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just because you need to use the [`CrawlSpider` class](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider) instead of the `BaseSpider`:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider

class DindexSpider(CrawlSpider):
    # ...
```

Comment: I eventually got the spider to run, but now it stops with this error  "  il.add_value('time', response['time'])
TypeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute '__getitem__' "

Comment: Funny all I did was change the parse_page to parse and it ran.  I am not sure why either.

Comment: Although the spider starts, it still shuts down and the issue of extracting certain items from one page and then following a link associated with those items still is not running.

Comment: If you use a CrawlSpider (as alecxe mentions) you mustn't define the `parse` function yourself because this method is needed by the spider itself and it makes sure the links are crawled. Your error message with `getitem` is because you use `response['ime']` instead of `response.meta['time']`.